# PCLAppConfig System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am building a Xamarin forms project and I use `PCLAppConfig` in the platform specific projects to get the app config file from the common project. This has been working until recently. Following an upgrade to Visual Studio(15.9.2) and the iOS OS(High Sierra 10.13.6) it stopped working for the iOS project (I have a feeling those changes are masking the real reason). I get the below error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: path: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0AC8F626-E2BD-4432-AC13-C761A1C95E1C/DemoApp.iOS.app/DemoApp.iOS.exe.config

To me it looks like it cannot find `app.config`

My main project still has an `app.config` and in the iOS specific project I can see an `App.config` (with a linked file symbol). Should the iOS specific project linked config have different casing?

**the code**

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
ConfigurationManager.Initialise(PCLAppConfig.FileSystemStream.PortableStream.Current);

LoadApplication(new App());
```

**also tried**

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings = new ConfigurationManager(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DemoApp.App.config"))
LoadApplication(new App());
```

**Edit - further info**

I have looked through the code base and in this case

`PCLAppConfig.FileSystemStream.PortableStream.Current`

is equivalent to

`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`

hopefully that will help with getting an answer

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the whole solution to see if it works. And can you find the `config` file through the path in your folder?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I lost count of how many times i tried that. I even deleted the whole repo and cloned it again

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue.

Was fixed in [1.0.1](https://github.com/mrbrl/PCLAppConfig/commit/046810927d29365be1a67edc3c45bbca2a97dca4#diff-34b5b5d8c9b635a010b3ea712f667d4b).